# Same version of PyInstaller builds app with splash screen on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: pyinstaller

I ran the same PyInstaller version 5.11.0 on the spec listed below on Windows and Linux:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas = []
binaries = []
hiddenimports = ['pyi_splash']
datas += collect_data_files('src')
datas += collect_data_files('kb_ftd2xx')
datas += collect_data_files('tkinter')
tmp_ret = collect_all('appcore')
datas += tmp_ret[0]; binaries += tmp_ret[1]; hiddenimports += tmp_ret[2]


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['src/Application.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=binaries,
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
splash = Splash(
    'src/gui/images/app_with_background.png',
    binaries=a.binaries,
    datas=a.datas,
    text_pos=(35, 320),
    text_size=9,
    text_color='#d3d3d3',
    minify_script=True,
    always_on_top=True,
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    splash,
    splash.binaries,
    [],
    name='Application',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

The resulting Linux binary ran successfully but the Windows binary error-ed out because of splash screen tcl font issues.

[image: Error dialog: splash cannot find requirement tk/ttk/cursors.tcl in archive]

A diff of the splash.toc generated on the Windows and Linux contains just one material difference -- a Boolean whose function I do not understand.

First 14 lines of splash.toc generated on Windows. (Take note of `False` on line 14)

```
('C:/repos/app/src/gui/images/app_with_background.png',
 'C:/repos/app/build/Application/Splash-00.res',
 'C:/repos/app/build/Application/Splash-00_script.tcl',
 (35, 320),
 9,
 'TkDefaultFont',
 '#d3d3d3',
 'Initializing',
 True,
 False,
 True,
 '__splash',
 (760, 480),
 False, <-----
```

First 14 lines of splash.toc generated on Linux. (Take note of `True` on line 14)

```
 ('/mnt/c/repos/app/src/gui/images/app_with_background.png',
 '/mnt/c/repos/app/build/Application/Splash-00.res',
 '/mnt/c/repos/app/build/Application/Splash-00_script.tcl',
 (35, 320),
 9,
 'TkDefaultFont',
 '#d3d3d3',
 'Initializing',
 True,
 False,
 True,
 '__splash',
 (760, 480),
 True, <-----
```

I don't know whether this Boolean is relevant.

Comment: This is a PyInstaller [bug](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7828) and has just been fixed on the development branch.